# Cassandra with JNA is slow (high IO)

Tags: cassandra, jna

we are using Cassandra 2.0.14 on a system with 64GB RAM, 8GB HEAP size, 32-core CPU, Java 1.7.
When JNA is loaded (as recommended in the production settings), it has negative effect on performance, especially when used with HDD => it significantly increases the IO wait.
It looks like JNA works fine only when used in combination with SSD disk. Otherwise it is better not to use JNA at all.

My questions are:

Has someone a similar experience? How is it possible that Java would outperform native file system operations (accessed via JNA)?

Can we use Cassandra without JNA for production usage? Are there any side effects?

Results (sorted by performance):

**a) HDD + JNA**
Worst performance. High IO wait.

**b) HDD, no JNA**
Good performance. Low IO wait, but the Cassandra CPU usage is quite high (500%)

**c) SSD + JNA**
Seems to provide the best performance. Low IO wait. Low Cassandra CPU usage (300%). But we can not always use SSD. This was rather a test it is not a solution for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, Cassandra uses JNA to lock the JVM into memory with mlockall to avoid the JVM to be swapped out. I guess the performance will be quite bad if the OS decides to swap out the JVM to disk...

I know in earlier versions of Cassandra, JNA was also used to create hardlinks, but since that's natively supported in Java >= 7, I think recent versions of Cassandra uses the Java API to create hardlinks instead of JNA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm not sure if that is the case. In my case the JNA made things **worse** when it was used with HDDs. That was really unexpected.